# Parallel Python doesn't give errors but parallel processing doesn't take place

Tags: python, parallel-python

I am new to python and Parallel Python. The problem is I have 4 jobs to be done: generation of 4 masks, multiplication of them with my input image, followed by further processing. Following is the piece of the code written for parallel processing.

```
inputs = range(4)
jobs = [(inpt, job_server.submit(PP, (inpt,input_data,size,(imageMultiply,blockCounter,imageQuantizer ), ("numpy","Image"))) for inpt in inputs]
job_server.print_stats()
for inpt, job in jobs:
  print "No of blocks in ", inpt, "is", job() ## accessing the result of pp
```

The output that I get is :

```
Starting pp with 4 workers
Job execution statistics:
 job count | % of all jobs | job time sum | time per job | job server
         4 |        100.00 |       0.0000 |     0.000000 | local
Time elapsed since server creation 0.0219678878784
4 active tasks, 4 cores

No of blocks in  0 is 52
No of blocks in  1 is 61
No of blocks in  2 is 104
No of blocks in  3 is 48
```

I cant understand that if its not processing simultaneously, still I am able to get the desired output, but the time taken is too big which is why I want to use pp.
Please help me with this so that I can successfully reduce the time.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should also call `print_stats()` after all the jobs are joined with `job()`. Then you can compare elapsed times measured with and without Parallel Python.  When you say "the time taken is too big," no one can tell how big it is actually;  1 min, 1 hour, 1 day, ...

Comment: @nodakai I wrote print_stats() after the last line and got following results:   Job execution statistics:
 job count | % of all jobs | job time sum | time per job | job server
         4 |        100.00 |      16.0401 |     4.010028 | local
Time elapsed since server creation 4.04183793068
0 active tasks, 4 cores

Answer (score 0):

From your `print_stats()` output (reformatted here,)

```
Job execution statistics:
 job count | % of all jobs | job time sum | time per job | job server
         4 |        100.00 |      16.0401 |     4.010028 | local
Time elapsed since server creation 4.04183793068
0 active tasks, 4 cores
```

everything seems to be fine.  You have 4 CPU cores; you could complete 4 jobs within 4 seconds after the creation of the job server;  the system consumed 16 CPU seconds in total to get all the jobs done.

You may want to try `top -H`, `htop` or `Windows Sysinternals Process Monitor` to observe CPU consumption in real time.

- http://hisham.hm/htop/
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: thanks for bringing that to my notice..But I have few doubts: 1) As you have pointed out, " the system consumed 16 CPU seconds in total to get all the jobs done", doesn't that mean that without pp the CPU would have taken 16 sec and after using 4 workers the system takes only 4 sec in total to get all the jobs done?? 2) In each of the 4 jobs that I have assigned, I display a processed image of my input image.So after the execution of my code, all the 4 images should be shown all at once due to use of pp. But I see them pop sequentially.What do I make out of this?plz help me understand

Comment: 1) Yes, that's what I meant.  Can you try passing `ncpus=1` when you instantiate a `Server` object to see how long it takes with 1 CPU?  2) No idea, maybe OS has to serialize disk I/O ops when you access the output image files?  Again, why don't you just run CPU usage monitors like shown above?  What platform do you use, Linux, OS X or Windows?